# How to create pointer to 2d array of chars?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, declaration, implicit-conversion

I am having trouble declaring pointer to 2d variable of chars...

```
    const char * d1 [][2] =
  {
    { "murderer", "termination specialist" },
    { "failure", "non-traditional success" },
    { "specialist", "person with certified level of knowledge" },
    { "dumb", "cerebrally challenged" },
    { "teacher", "voluntary knowledge conveyor" },
    { "evil", "nicenest deprived" },
    { "incorrect answer", "alternative answer" },
    { "student", "client" },
    { NULL, NULL }
  };
  char ( * ptr ) [2] = d1;
```

That is my code.
Error I am getting is
error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'char (*)[2]' with an lvalue of type 'const char *[9][2]'
What is happening and how can I fix it?
Thanks everyone.
char ( * ptr ) [2] = d1;

Comment: Consider using a struct instead as that will make your program far more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared a two-dimensional array like

```
const char * d1 [][2]
```

Elements of the array have the type `const char *[2]`.

So a declaration of a pointer to the first element of the array will look like

```
const char * ( * ptr ) [2] = d1;
```

The array `d1` used as an initializer is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

Using the pointer arithmetic you can access any element of the original array.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    const char *d1[][2] =
    {
      { "murderer", "termination specialist" },
      { "failure", "non-traditional success" },
      { "specialist", "person with certified level of knowledge" },
      { "dumb", "cerebrally challenged" },
      { "teacher", "voluntary knowledge conveyor" },
      { "evil", "nicenest deprived" },
      { "incorrect answer", "alternative answer" },
      { "student", "client" },
      { NULL, NULL }
    };
    const size_t N = sizeof( d1 ) / sizeof( *d1 );
    const char * ( *ptr )[2] = d1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N && ptr[i][0] != NULL; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            printf( "\"%s\" ", ptr[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
"murderer" "termination specialist"
"failure" "non-traditional success"
"specialist" "person with certified level of knowledge"
"dumb" "cerebrally challenged"
"teacher" "voluntary knowledge conveyor"
"evil" "nicenest deprived"
"incorrect answer" "alternative answer"
"student" "client"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand it much better!

Comment: @MatoušKovář If the problem is resolved then close th question by selecting the best answer and your reputation will be increased.:)